# Find all permutations with a condition in c

Tags: c, algorithm

I would like to generate, in c, all the arrays of length L where the total sum N of the elements is fixed. For example for L=3 and N=2 one should get

```
 {0,0,2}, 
 {0,1,1},
 {0,2,0},
 {1,0,1},
 {1,1,0},
 {2,0,0}
```

I have found several post on how to do it in Mathematica, but what is an efficient way to do it in c?

I was thinking in using the representation in base 3 to generate all the possible numbers and then take the digits one by one and put them into an array.

The conversion in base 3 can be done with

```
int BaseConvert(int number,int base){
    if(number == 0 || base==10) return number;

    return (number % base) + 10*BaseConvert(number / base, base);
}
```

The last part can be done with

```
void ConvertNumberToVec(int x,std::vector<int> & vec)
{
    int digit;
    std::vector<int> vec0;

    while(x > 0){
        digit = x%10;
        vec0.push_back(digit);
        x /= 10;
    }
    std::reverse(vec0.begin(), vec0.end());
    vec = vec0;
}
```

or it is a better way to do it?

Comment: With negative values also?

Comment: If you want to do it in C why have you tagged C++? Are you accepting C++ answerrs? I[f so, investigate `std::next_permutation`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation)

Comment: @user4581301 Those aren't pernutations.

Comment: You got me there.

Comment: I have changed the title. I am looking for an implementation in C. No negative values, just from 0 to N

Comment: @rici You are right, actually they are not permutations. I've removed the flag

Answer (score 0):

You can write recursive algorithm:

```
permutation = []
f(L, N):
  if L is 0:
    if N is 0:
      print permutation
    return
  for i in 0..N:
    permutation.push_back(i)
    f(L - 1, N - i)
    permutation.pop_back()
```

easy to code with c.

Comment: I think you want to condition the print with `if N is 0`.